# Why the image blurs when it is in motion tween?

Tags: html, animation, flash

I had atleast 20 images.i tried to move it scroll from right to left in Flash MX 2004. When i pr viewed in timeline window it shows actual image moving. But when i exported it into swf it shows as a Blurred image moving.

The movie is at  http://www.ahilam.com/tes.swf

How to solve this. Plz help. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about deacreasing the amount of horizontal movement per step and/or increasing the framerate.. ?